# how to create a small constant relation(table) in pig?

Tags: apache-pig

is there a way to create a small constant relation(table) in pig?
I need to create a relation with only 1 tuple that contains constant values. 
something along the lines of:

```
A = LOAD using ConstantLoader('{(1,2,3)}');
```

thanks, Ido

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?  And why couldn't you accomplish it by using `%DECLARE` or passing in several parameters which contain these constants?

Comment: I'm using a macro that demands a relation as a parameter, and I want to pass an empty relation

Comment: I need the same. This is related to stackoverflow.com/questions/12423399/define-tuple-datas-in-the-pig-script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fast answer: no.

I asked about it in [pig-dev mailing list](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/pig-dev/201408.mbox/%3CCAB2zpW8of3juRKzRrva72mc_7T7D8bRFB2+b4sS-tryCZbiVBg@mail.gmail.com%3E).

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why you would need that but, here's an ugly solution:

```
A = LOAD 'some/sample/file' ;
B = FOREACH A GENERATE '' ;
C = LIMIT A 1 ;
```

Now, you can use 'C' as the 'empty relation' that has one empty tuple.

Comment: thanks, indeed ugly :) note that it would get uglier if you want a relation with 2 records, say `{(1,2)(3,4)}`

Answer (score 2):

```
DEFINE GenerateRelationFromString(string) RETURNS relation {
    temp = LOAD 'somefile';
    tempLimit1 = LIMIT temp 1;
    $relation = FOREACH tempLimit1 GENERATE FLATTEN(TOKENIZE('$string', ','));
};
```

usage:

```
fourRows = GenerateRelationFromString('1,2,3,4');
myConstantRelation = FOREACH fourRows GENERATE ( 
CASE $0
    WHEN '1' THEN (1, 'Ivan')
    WHEN '2' THEN (2, 'Boris')
    WHEN '3' THEN (3, 'Vladimir')
    WHEN '4' THEN (4, 'Olga')
END
) as myTuple;
```

This for sure is hacky, and the right way, in my mind, would be to implement a StringLoader() that would work like this:

```
fourRows = LOAD '1,2,3,4' USING StringLoader(',');
```

The argument typically used for file location would just be used as litral string input.