# pig - how to make aggregate function (MAX) to return a constant value when the relation(table) is empty?

Tags: apache-pig

I'm applying an aggregate function over an entire table:

```
 G = group A by all;
 M = foreach G generate MAX(my_column);
```

which of course returns the maximum value of my_column in the entire A relation(table).

however, when A is empty, the result M is also empty.
Can someone think of a trick, how can I force M in such a case to contain a constant value of 0?

(note: this question might be related to [how to create a small constant relation(table) in pig?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13414172/how-to-create-a-small-constant-relationtable-in-pig) but it could be that there's a separate answer to each of them)

Thanks, Ido

Answer (score 0):

Use a ternary operator and [IsEmpty](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.7.0/piglatin_ref2.html#IsEmpty):

```
M = foreach G generate (IsEmpty(A) ? 0 : MAX(my_column));
```

Comment: sorry, this is wrong. A is empty, so G is also empty, so M comes out empty as well... test it and see that it outputs an empty relation :(